# How to restore a database with SMK and Cerificate to another computer

Tags: sql-server, encryption

On ComputerA, I have a database with SMK and a certificate. I've created this with the following code:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password123';
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate1
WITH SUBJECT = 'Protect Data';
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1 
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128 
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;
GO
```

Now I have created a backup file for this to restore it on ComputerB. The restore works fine but when I try to execute the following code on ComputerB:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;
GO
-- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID 
SELECT Customer_id, Credit_card_number_encrypt AS 'Encrypted Credit Card Number',
CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(Credit_card_number_encrypt)) AS 'Decrypted Credit Card Number'
FROM dbo.Customer_data;

 -- Close the symmetric key
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1;
```

It returns the error:

```
Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.
The key 'SymmetricKey1' is not open. Please open the key before using it.
```

I've tried deleting the SMK and Cert. under the Security Folder it still returns the same error. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you might be encountering the same problem as [How to restore symmetric key on the new database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65531/how-to-restore-symmetric-key-on-the-new-database/159420).  Excerpted from the accepted answer on that post:

> A symmetric key that was created without specifying the `KEY_SOURCE` and
>   `IDENTITY_VALUE` can never be scripted or copied.

If you can recreate the symmetric key on the source database and specify the `KEY_SOURCE` and `IDENTITY_VALUE`, I think you will be able to open it on the target server.

Referencing [Create Identical Symmetric Keys on Two Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-identical-symmetric-keys-on-two-servers?view=sql-server-2017):

> In order to decrypt ciphertext, you need the key that was used to
>   encrypt it. When both encryption and decryption occur in a single
>   database, the key is stored in the database and it is available,
>   depending on permissions, for both encryption and decryption. But when
>   encryption and decryption occur in separate databases or on separate
>   servers, the key stored in one database is not available for use on
>   the second database

From that post, here is an example of creating a symmetric key using  `KEY_SOURCE` and `IDENTITY_VALUE`:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'My p@55w0Rd';  
GO  
CREATE CERTIFICATE [cert_keyProtection] WITH SUBJECT = 'Key Protection';  
GO  
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY [key_DataShare] WITH  
    KEY_SOURCE = 'My key generation bits. This is a shared secret!',  
    ALGORITHM = AES_256,   
    IDENTITY_VALUE = 'Key Identity generation bits. Also a shared secret'  
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [cert_keyProtection];  
GO
```

On the target server, after your restore, you *might* need to run the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- When a backup is restored to a different server, the following script must be run
-- so the encrypted data will be accessible with the standard stored procedures.
-- Run this in the database containing the encrypted data.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<original password>';
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- This will alter the master key to drop service master key encryption
-- The service master key is server-specific so it's tied
-- to the server the backup came from.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER MASTER KEY DROP ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY; 
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- This will alter the master key to add new service master key 
-- encryption based on the current server.
-- This is done so you don't have to open the master key
-- with a password each time you use the certificate and symmetric key.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
GO
CLOSE MASTER KEY;
```